# How to calculate the likelihood for a normal distribution N(theta, 1) if we only know the maximum of a sample?

Tags: normal-distribution, likelihood

Assuming iid samples x ~ N(theta, 1), we have a sample of 5 observations with maximum value = 3. How to calculate the likelihood?

Comment: The sample is the maximum, which has a well-defined distribution, hence the likelihood.

Comment: You can find the CDF for the maximum, take its derivative for the pdf for the maximum, and use this (or something proportional to this) as the likelihood for $\theta$ given the maximum of the observations.   The maximum in this case will be at about $x_{(5)}-1.0615$

Comment: This is a special case of the situation analyzed (and solved, with working code) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/130174/919.