# Easier way to find $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{(2)}| X_{(1)}, X_{(3)}\right]$?

Tags: uniform-distribution, conditional-expectation, order-statistics

Consider 3 iid samples  drawn from the uniform distribution  $u(\theta, 2\theta)$, where $\theta$ is parameter. I want to find 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{(2)}| X_{(1)}, X_{(3)}\right]
$$ 
where $X_{(i)}$ is order statistic $i$.

I would expect the result to be 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{(2)}| X_{(1)}, X_{(3)}\right] = \frac{X_{(1)}+ X_{(3)}}{2}
$$
But the only way I can show this result seems to be too lengthy, I cannot come up with simple solution, am I missing something, is there some shortcut?

---

What I do is the following:

- I find the conditional density

  $$
  f(x_{(2)}| x_{(1)}, x_{(3)}) = \frac{ f(x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}, x_{(3)})}{f(x_{(1)}, x_{(3)})}
  $$
- I integrate

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{(2)}| X_{(1)}, X_{(3)}\right] = \int x f(x| x_{(1)}, x_{(3)}) 
dx $$

---

Details:

I adopt general formula for density of order statistic
(with $\mathbb{I}_{\{A\}}$ an indicator of set $A$)

$$
f_{x_{(1)},\ldots , x_{(n)}}(x_1,\cdots, x_n) = n! \prod_{i=1}^n f_{x}(x_i)\mathbb{I}_{\{x_{(1)} \leq x_{(2)} \leq \cdots \leq x_{(n)}\}}(x_1,\cdots, x_n) 
$$

to obtain for my case

$$
f_{x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}, x_{(3)}}(x_1, x_2, x_3) = 3!\frac{1}{\theta^3}\mathbb{I}_{\{x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \cdots \leq x_n\}}(x_1,\cdots, x_3) 
$$

marginal of $f_{x_{(1)}, x_{(3)}}(u, v)$ is

$$f_{x_{(1)}, x_{(3)}}(u, v) = \int f_{x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}, x_{(3)}}(u, x_2, v) dx_2$$

that is

$$
f_{x_{(1)}, x_{(3)}}(u, v) = \int 3!\frac{1}{\theta^3}\mathbb{I}_{\{x_1 = u \leq x_2 \leq x_3 = v\}}(u, x, v) dx = 3!\frac{1}{\theta^3} [v-u]
$$

therefor

$$
 f(x_{(2)}| x_{(2)} = u, x_{(3)} = v) =
\frac{ f(x_{(1)} = u, x_{(2)}, x_{(3)} = v)}{f(x_{(1)}= u, x_{(3)} = v)} = \frac{3!\frac{1}{\theta^3}\mathbb{I}_{u \leq x_2 \leq \cdots \leq v}(u,x_2, v) }{3!\frac{1}{\theta^3} [v-u]}= [v-u]^{-1}\mathbb{I}_{\{u<x_2<v\}}
$$

which gives

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{(2)}| X_{(1)} = u, X_{(3)} = v\right] = [v-u]^{-1}\int_{u}^{v} x dx = 
[v-u]^{-1}\frac{
[v^2 - u^2]}{2} = 
\frac{u+v}{2}
$$

Comment: I didn't look at what you did, but you got an answer of $\frac{u - v}{2}$, not $\frac{u + v}{2}$

Comment: @MarkL.Stone you are right... I fixed that, the last line, integral of $\int x dx$ was incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the $X_i$ all have a uniform distribution, all (unordered) variables are assumed independent, *and no other order statistic lies between $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(3)}$,* $X_{(2)}$ has a truncated uniform distribution supported on the interval $[X_{(1)}, X_{(3)}]$.  Its mean obviously is $(X_{(1)}+X_{(3)})/2$, *QED.*

---

If you would like a formal demonstration, note that when the $X_i$ are iid with an absolutely continuous distribution $F$, the conditional density of $X_{(k)}$ (conditional on all the other order statistics) is $dF(x_k)/(F(x_{(k+1)}) - F(x_{(k-1)}))$, which is the truncated distribution.  (When $k=1$, $F(x_{0})$ is taken to be $0$; and when $k=n$, $F(x_{n+1})$ is taken to be $1$.)  This follows from [Joint pdf of functions of order statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78546), for instance, together with the definition of conditional densities.

Comment: whuber, when you write $dF(x_k)$ you refer to the probability density of X, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  By definition, $$dF(x)=\frac{d F}{d x}(x)\,dx.$$  (Technically, I should have called this the "probability element" rather than the "density".)