# Distribution of the relative range ($R/\sigma$)

Tags: normal-distribution, terminology, notation, dispersion, sampling-distribution

Let us assume a $n$-sized random sample $\{ X_1 , \dots, X_n \}$ from a random variable $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$.

Let

- $X_\mathrm{min} = \mathrm{min}\{ X_1 , \dots, X_n \}$
- $X_\mathrm{max} = \mathrm{max}\{ X_1 , \dots, X_n \}$

and let the range be defined as usual:

- $R = X_\mathrm{max} - X_\mathrm{min}$.

Let us also define the following sample statistic:

- $W = R\;/\;\sigma$.

My question is: **What is the distribution of $W$?**

The population parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are assumed to be *known* (and constant, of course).

In some slides, I've read that $W$ can be assumed to follow a normal distribution, but I am not sure of whether this is an approximation or an exact result.

Since $\sigma$ is assumed to be constant, I am actually asking for the distribution of the range from normally distributed data.

Another question is this one: **I know $W$ can be called the 'relative range'. Is there a more widespread or popular name? Is $W$ the most common notation, or is there any other recommended notation?**

Comment: $W$ is not a sample statistic because it depends on the unknown parameter $\sigma.$  When you instead divide $R$ by the sample standard deviation, you obtain the [Studentized Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range).

Comment: My question was about $R/\sigma$ assuming that $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are both known (and constant). Maybe the slides I saw were referring to the studentised range. Anyway, I am going to keep my question open (after properly editing it).

Comment: Please realize that in this case neither $\mu$ nor $\sigma$ matters: the distribution of $W$ does not depend on them.  That reduces the answer to a straightforward formula, given in detail at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427419/distribution-of-ranges-of-normally-distributed-variables.