# Conditional distances in order statistics

Tags: uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Assume I have $n$ points sampled independently from the uniform distribution on the unit interval. After ordering the sample I get the points $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$ such that $X_1 \leq X_2 \leq \dots \leq X_n$. According to the [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) the distances are beta-distributed:

$$Y_{jk} = X_k - X_j \sim \text{Beta}(k-j,n-(k-j)+1), \quad k >j.$$

Now, I have some constant threshold value $d$ and need to calculate the following probability:

$$p = \mathbb{P}[(Y_{12} \leq d)\,\,\text{and}\,\, (Y_{13} > d)]$$

Using the rules of probability calculus I get

$$p = 1 - \mathbb{P}[Y_{12} > d] - \mathbb{P}[Y_{13} \leq d] + \mathbb{P}[(Y_{12} > d)\,\,\text{and}\,\, (Y_{13} \leq d)] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[Y_{12} > d] - \mathbb{P}[Y_{13} \leq d]$$

Here I have used the fact that $(Y_{12} > d)$ and $(Y_{13} \leq d)$ are mutually exclusive events in order statistics. The final probability $p$ can be calculated using the CDF of the beta distribution.

Now, I'm stuck in calculating a more complex probability:

$$\mathbb{P}[(Y_{12} > d)\,\,\text{and}\,\, (Y_{23} \leq d)\,\,\text{and}\,\, (Y_{24} > d)].$$

Could someone help me in solving the problem.

Comment: You need to compute the joint distribution of $(Y_{12},Y_{23},Y_{34})$ since $Y_{24}=Y_{23}+Y_{34}$.

Comment: @Xi'an Do I really need that? I believe there could be an other way since I was able to calculate my $p$ without computing the joint distribution of $(Y_{12}, Y_{23})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the [density function of the joint distribution of the first four order statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78559/919) $(Y_{(1)}, Y_{(2)}, Y_{(3)}, Y_{(4)})$ is

$$f_(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4) = \frac{n!}{(n-4)!} (1-y_4)^{n-4}\, \mathcal{I}(0 \le y_1 \le y_2 \le y_3 \le y_4 \le 1)$$

and $Y_{ij} = Y_{(j)} - Y_{(i)},$ the probability in question is

$$\begin{aligned}
&\Pr(Y_{12}\ge d, Y_{23} \le d, Y_{24} \gt d) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} \cdots \int_{\mathbb R} f(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)\,\mathrm{d}y_1 \cdots \mathrm{d}y_4 \\
&= \frac{n!}{(n-4)!}\int_{\max(y_3, \min(1,y_2+d))}^1\int_{y_2}^{\min(1, y_2+d)}\int_{\min(1,y_1+d)}^1\int_0^1(1-y_4)^{n-4}\,\mathrm{d}y_1 \cdots \mathrm{d}y_4\\
&= n d (1-2d)^{n-1}
\end{aligned}$$

for $0 \le d \le 1/2$ and $n\ge 4.$

**This is supported by simulations**, as in this example based on $10^5$ independent samples of size $n=5:$

[image: Figure]

The points show the simulation results, in comparison with the red graph of the computed probability.

**You can work out the answers to comparable questions the same way,** although evidently the calculations will become more complicated as more order statistics are involved in the description of the event.